# Cannot assign requested address: connect

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm getting this error when I call any Maven command:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:jar:3.1.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:pom:3.1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/3.1.0/maven-enforcer-plugin-3.1.0.pom: Cannot assign requested address: connect -> [Help 1]
```

Things that I've already checked:

```
1. Windows Firewall is not blocking outbound/inbound requests
2. Not behind any proxy
3. Connected to the internet
4. Settings file credentials and repo url OK     <settings>    
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>maven-snapshots</id>
            <username>dummy-username</username>
            <password>dummy-pwd</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>maven-releases</id>
            <username>dummy-username</username>
            <password>dummy-pwd</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>local</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>maven-releases</id>
                <url>https://dev-repo.tech5-sa.com/repository/maven-releases/</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>

5. Can access repo using browser
6. Cleaned caches
```

This was also happening with Gradle - this:  **Cannot assign requested address: connect** - , before I switch the project to be under Maven control, so I'm guessing, some configuration in the machine (Machine is new).

```
Java version: 11.0.16
Apache Maven 3.8.7

IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1
Build #IC-223.8214.52, built on December 20, 202
```

Can anyone give me some hints ?

Thank You for your time.

Leo

Comment: Can you run `curl https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/3.1.0/maven-enforcer-plugin-3.1.0.pom` in your terminal? Do you get a valid POM back?

Comment: Do you see any errors related to "transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/" in the idea.log file?